# How to use 'create-hive-table' with Sqoop correctly?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I'm trying to import data from MySQL table to Hive using Sqoop. From what I understood there are 2 ways of doing that.

1. Import data into HDFS and then create External Table in Hive and load data into that table.
2. Use `create-hive-table` while running Sqoop query to create a new table in Hive and directly load data into that. I am trying to do this but can't do it for some reason

This is my code

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMPLOYEE \
--username root \
--password root \
--table emp \
--m 1 \
--hive-database sqoopimport \
--hive-table sqoopimport.employee \
--create-hive-table \
--fields-terminated-by ',';
```

I tried using `--hive-import` as well but got error.
When I ran the above query, job was successful but there was no table created in hive as well as data was stored in `\user\HDFS\emp\` location where `\HDFS\emp` was created during the job.

PS: Also I could not find any reason for using `--m 1` with Sqoop. It's just there in all queries.

Answer (score 1):

I got the import working with following query. There is no need to write `create-hive-table` we can just write new table name with `hive-table` and that table will be created. Also if there is any issue then go to `hive-metastore` location and run `rm *.lck` then try import again.

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMPLOYEE \
--username root \
--password root \
--table emp4 \
--hive-import \
--hive-table sqoopimport.emp4 \
--fields-terminated-by "," ;
```